# How to disallow adding of existing options to select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to not allow values that already exist in select options? (using jQuery)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  if ($('#new-option').val() != '') {
    var val = $('#new-option').val();
    $('#foo option:last').html(val);
    var opt = '<option>Other</option>';
    $('#foo').append(opt);
    $('#foo').val(val);
    $('#new-option').val('');
    console.log($("#foo option").each(function() {
      $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="foo">
  <option>Notification</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="new-option" required>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Option</button>
```

Comment: Add new elements to an array only if they don't already exist in the array. Then build your select list from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the current values and only append if not already present. See inline comments for details:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {

  var found = false;  // Track if new value was found in list
  
  // Loop through list options
  $("#foo > option").each(function(idx, el){
    // Compare (case-insensitive) new value against list values
    if($("#new-option").val().toLowerCase() === el.textContent.toLowerCase()){
      found = true;  // Set flag if value exists
    }
  });

  // If not found
  if(!found){
    // Create new option and append to list
    var opt = '<option>' + $("#new-option").val()  + '</option>';
    $('#foo').append(opt);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="foo">
  <option>Notification</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="new-option" required>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Option</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through each select option and check if it exists or not. Use jQuery. Use jQuery `.trim()` to remove space in comparison.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
    if($('#new-option').val() != '')
    {
        var val = $('#new-option').val();
        var flag_add = true;
       $("#foo").find("option").each(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
            if($(this).val().trim()==val.trim()){
                flag_add = false;
                alert("Option already added...")
                return;
            }    
        });
        if(flag_add)
        {
            $('#foo option:last').html(val);
            var opt = '<option>Other</option>';
            $('#foo').append(opt);
            $('#foo').val(val);
            $('#new-option').val('');
        }
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="foo">
  <option>Notification</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="new-option" required>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Option</button>
```

Comment: Please don't link to external resources when you can embed working code right here. External links may become bad over time and then your answer won't make as much sense.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Marcus  next time I will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :
Two more things need to take care:
 1. more then one whitespace in text field `.trim()` should fix it.
 2. checking case as `Other` and `other` will be treated as different.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
 var option_to_add = $("#new-option").val();
 var options = [];
 $("#foo option").each(function(){
      options.push($(this).text())
 });

 if(option_to_add != '')
 {

   if($.inArray(option_to_add,options) === -1)
   {
      $("#foo").append("<option>"+option_to_add+"</option>");
   }
   else
   {
      alert("Option already exists");
   }
 }
 else
 {
  alert("Empty value");
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved your issue please replace your script by this i have code

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
      if ($('#new-option').val() != '') {
        var val = $('#new-option').val();
        if($("#foo option[value='"+val+"']").length > 0){
         alert('already present');
        }else{
          var opt = '<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>';
          $('#foo').append(opt);
        }
        $('#new-option').val(''); 
      }

    });
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Please don't title your answers with bold face "Solved your issue..." Instead, explain what the problem was and how your code addressed it. Without this information, the answer may work, but could be unintelligible for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
var val = $('#new-option').val();
if(val != ''){
    var arr = $('#foo').children('option').map(function(i,el){return $(el).text()});
    if($.makeArray(arr).indexOf(val) != -1){
        alert("this option exists...")
    }else{
        $('#foo').append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
        $('#new-option').val('');
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lodash` library, you can use the `some` function which can "find" if there's at least 1 item, in the given array, matches the condition (here the equality between the text of each option and the new option).

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {
  var newoption = $("#new-option").val();
  var options = $("#foo option");
  if (newoption != "") {
    if(!_.some(options, function(opt) { return $(opt).text() == newoption; })) {
      $("#foo").append("<option>" + newoption + "</option>");
      console.log(newoption + " added");
    } else {
      console.log(newoption + " not added");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<select id="foo">
  <option>Notification</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="new-option" required>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Option</button>
```

Comment: Why use the library for such a small thing. We can use simple jQuery.

Comment: Because the code you have to write is smaller. And, if you need the same behavior anywhere else in your application, you don't need to duplicate your code to loop. We can ask also "why jQeury" and not using "native javascript" ? It's because library helps us to make our code simpler.

Comment: @MayurPatel Or, we can use simple JavaScript, which already exposes a `some()` array function.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Please do not create answers that require technologies other than what the OP has tagged the question with. There are a variety of reasons not to do this including the fact that the OP may be working in an environment where the use of 3rd party libraries is out of their control or they may have bandwidth issues. Also, writing smaller code does not automatically equal better code.